# How to find latest 2 result with specific alpabet but with same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

Raw Data

```
+---------+--------+------------+
|   ID    | STATUS |    DATE    |
+---------+--------+------------+
| ABC1234 | P      | 2020-01-01 |
| ABC1234 | P      | 2020-01-02 |
| ABC1234 | B      | 2020-01-03 |
| ABC1234 | A      | 2020-01-04 |
| ABC1234 | A      | 2020-01-05 |
| BCD     | P      | 2020-01-01 |
| BCD     | P      | 2020-01-02 |
| BCD     | P      | 2020-01-03 |
| BCD     | B      | 2020-01-04 |
| BCD     | A      | 2020-01-05 |
| 12XY    | P      | 2020-01-01 |
| 12XY    | P      | 2020-01-02 |
| 12XY    | P      | 2020-01-03 |
| 12XY    | B      | 2020-01-04 |
| 12XY    | B      | 2020-01-05 |
+---------+--------+------------+
```

Result I want

```
+-----+--------+------------+
| ID  | STATUS |    DATE    |
+-----+--------+------------+
| BCD | B      | 2020-01-04 |
| BCD | A      | 2020-01-05 |
+-----+--------+------------+
```

How to find result whereby latest record Status=A, and second latest record Status=B?

Tried on below but still missing idea how get for ID=BCD

```
select ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date2 DESC) AS rownum
         ,*
         into testingtable
         from mytable
         WHERE status in ('b', 'a')
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to find result whereby latest record `Status=A`, and second latest record `Status=B`?

You can use window functions and a little bit of boolean logic:

```
select id, status, date
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by status order by date desc) rn
    from mytable t
    where status in ('A', 'B')
) t
where (status = 'A' and rn = 1) or (status = 'B' and rn = 2)
```

Comment: I don't think `partition by status` is going to do the right thing. By `id`, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Remove where clause from subquery & use boolean logic :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over(partition by id order by date desc) as seq
      from table t
      ) t
where (status = 'A' and seq = 1) or (status = 'B' and seq = 2) ;
```